Is there any way to know that the selected window for screen sharing is closed in firefox browser?
When using the MediaStream API to capture a screen recording in Firefox, it's challenging to detect when the selected window for screen sharing is closed. The MediaStreamTrack object provides several events, such as ended and inactive, but these events are not  fired when the user closes the selected window.
Note: This issue is specific to Firefox, as Chrome, Safari, and Edge browsers work correctly in this scenario.
Following is the code i am using right now:
screenRecordingStream.value =
    await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(
        displayMediaOptions
    );
screenRecordingStream.value.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    track.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        debugger;
        if (isRecording.value) {
            completionStatus.value = true;
            stopMediaRecorder();
        }
    });
    track.addEventListener('inactive', () => {
        debugger;
        if (isRecording.value) {
            completionStatus.value = true;
            stopMediaRecorder();
        } else {
            changeMode(1);
        }
    });
    track.addEventListener('inactive', () => {
        console.log('Track inactive');
        // ...
    });
    track.addEventListener('mute', () => {
        console.log('Track muted');
    });
    track.addEventListener('unmute', () => {
        console.log('Track unmuted');
    });
    track.addEventListener('overconstrained', () => {
        console.log('Track overconstrained');
    });
    track.addEventListener('readyStateChange', () => {
        console.log('Track ready state changed');
    });
});

I have tried testing it in other browser and it is working as expected. Recording stopped when the selected tab or window is closed. In case of firefox when the selected tab or window is that event is not detected.

.. They indeed seem happy to keep feeding the stream with the last frame, without giving any clue that the window has been closed. The specs say that an ended event must be fired when the display becomes definitely "inaccessible", but they also say that UAs decide what "inaccessible" means... I agree with you that a closed window should match, but on the other hand that may also be seen as yet another layer of security to only hide the capturing notification when the user actually clicks it to end the capture. This may avoid single click record tab + close before user notices.

But still, you may want to open an issue at https://bugzil.la

I reported this issue on Bugzilla and found out it's a bug. The fix will be in the next Firefox update, version 128.
